# nth-child selector in css

Tags: css, selector, css-selectors

i am curious to know how the nth-child css selector works. I was expecting the following code to change the background color for the 3rd

element, that is "The third paragraph". However, when I run this code, the 2nd

element is getting selected and "The second paragraph" has a changed background color.

```
<html>
<head>
<style> 
p:nth-child(3) {
    background: #ff0000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>The first paragraph.</p>
<p>The second paragraph.</p>
<p>The third paragraph.</p>
<p>The fourth paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Since `<p>` is not a child of any ancestor and it cordially counts `<h1>`, you need to use [`:nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) to target the third paragraph

```
p:nth-of-type(3) {
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

### [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4929059h/)

Answer (score 1):

`nth-child` does not care for the type of the other elements, so it also counts the `h1` element.

You can archive what you want using `p:nth-of-type(3)`

EDIT: Clarification

Comment: I hope this makes it a little clearer what I meant :)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you're specifying a paragraph that is the `nth-child` of it's parent. Since the parent is `body`, and you're asking for `n` to be 3, it will be the second `p` in your markup.