# selecting the second <a> tag inside a div element

Tags: html, css

I want to select just the second a tag (which is the fourth element in the code below) inside a div. My HTML looks like this:

```
   <div class="portItemContainer">
        <div class="portItem">
            <a href="#"><img src="Images/img.png" alt="" /></a>
            <h5>Website Title</h5>
            <h6>CREATIVE</h6>
            **<a href="">Visit The Website</a>**
            <p>
                some text
            </p>
        </div>
```

What is the best way to do it?
Thanks

Comment: Plesase Give desire op...

Comment: What do you mean "select a tag"?

Comment: Always do a search before you ask questions.

Comment: I edited the title to reflect what the OP wanted to ask

Comment: possible duplicate of [nth-child selector in css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26093889/nth-child-selector-in-css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`:nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) psuedo selector.

```
.portItem a:nth-of-type(2){
    color:red;
}
```

Or

You can use [adjacent siblings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) selector

```
.portItem <h6> + a{
   color:red;
}
```

### [**Demo 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/mxnz477k/)

---

### [**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/mxnz477k/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
 .portItem h6 + a { 
      /*styles here */
 }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/7mspqaLr/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nth-of-type` for this

```css
.portItem a:nth-of-type(2) {
  color:red;
  }
```

```html
 <div class="portItemContainer">
        <div class="portItem">
            <a href="#">Some Text</a>
            <h5>Website Title</h5>
            <h6>CREATIVE</h6>
            <a href="">Visit The Website</a>**
            <p>
                some text
            </p>
        </div>
```